# How can I select the first n results of each element in a WHERE .. IN clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table containing multiple computer names and the date of a connection. Here's an example.

```
ID    Computer         User         Date         
------------------------------------------------
1      O-1234          User1         2010-07-08        
2      O-1234          User2         2010-08-24           
3      O-1234          User2         2010-09-25
4      O-1555          User3         2010-08-24           
5      O-1555          User3         2010-09-25
```

I would like to be able to only select the last 2 or 3 connections for each computer. Also, I can't modify the table. Anybody have an idea ?

Thank you

EDIT: It's a MS Access mdb file

EDIT": Since RANK OVER() can't be used in MS Access, would it be possible to use a temporary table to do the job ?

Comment: What DBMS are you using here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Computer, User, Date,
    RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Computer ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM YourTable)
WHERE RowNumber <= 3
```

EDIT: Oh... it's Access.

I don't have access to... er... Access, but can try this instead?

```
SELECT
    logins.ID,
    logins.Computer,
    logins.User,
    logins.Date,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    YourTable logins INNER JOIN
    YourTable Subsequentlogins ON
        logins.Computer = Subsequentlogins.Computer
        AND logins.Date <= Subsequentlogins.Date
GROUP BY
    logins.ID,
    logins.Computer,
    logins.User,
    logins.Date
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
```

Comment: I understand that     RANK() OVER is not available in ms access would it be possible to make a sub request to mimic the effect of this command ?

Comment: I know it's far from the best thing to use but sadly it's not my decision... i'll try your solution and come back to you soon

Comment: I just added INNER JOIN since i was having an error with the query and it worked. Thank you very much Michael

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to partition/rank them somehow, which can be pretty database-dependent.  If you indicate what database you are using we can give more specific help.

For SQL Server, for example, it would look something like this

```
SELECT
    Computer
    ,User
    ,Date
    ,LoginRank
FROM
    (SELECT
         Computer
         ,User
         ,Date
         ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Computer ORDER BY Date DESC) as LoginRank
     FROM
         Logins)
WHERE
    LoginRank in (1,2)  -- take the top 2
ORDER BY
    Computer
    ,LoginRank ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for trying Daniel, with the help of Michael o found the answer. Have a nice day !